# For a form the GET method is not supported for this route

Tags: php, laravel, forms, routes, get

I have set the POST method for inserting data in a form. I have set the POST method in web.php also. But whenever I want to insert data through form it shows that Get method is not supported. But I have write the POST method in both form and route. Here is my code:

Form:

```
<form action="{{url('/admin/prescription/store')}}" method="POST"> 
@csrf

Route::post('/admin/prescription/store','prescriptionController@store')->name('prescription.store');
```

Controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $prescription = new Prescription();
    $prescription->full_name = $request->full_name;
    $prescription->nid = $request->nid;
    $prescription->address = $request->address;
    $prescription->contactNum = $request->contactNum;
    $prescription->health_cond = $request->health_cond;
    $prescription->desc = $request->desc;
    $prescription->save();
     
    return redirect()
        ->route('prescription.store')
        ->with('success','Prescription added Successfully.');
 }
```

Comment: Look at the this 
return redirect()
        ->route('prescription.store')
        ->with('success','Prescription added Successfully.');
so this you are returning flash data to this route with redirect so eventually making it get request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of your redirect in store(), you should redirect to a get Route

Comment: Yes I had to redirect index page. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This is because of your redirect to a post Route. Redirect works as get request.

Comment: Thanks. I could Fix it

Answer (score 1):

To use one route for both types of requests, you could do:

```
Route::match(['GET', 'POST'],'/admin/prescription/store', 'ExampleController@store');
```